# Find if CountDownTimer is Finished?

Tags: android, if-statement, countdown

I was playing around with the CountDownTimer on Android and I came into sort of a dilemma. In my code, I have the following:

```
public class mCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer{
    protected boolean hasFinished = false;
    public mCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public void onFinish(){
        hasFinished = true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Basically I want to find out if my CountDownTimer has finished. But in the function I want to call it in, I have some code that goes:

```
public void function(){
public boolean finished = false;
    if(interrupted)
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    if(temporaryCountHolder == false){
        countDownTimer.start();
        interrupted = true;
    }
}
```

How can i tell whether or not my timer has finished? I want to implement something that says:

```
 if(countDownTimer.hasFinished == true){
        Time now = new Time(); //finds the current time
        now.setToNow(); 
        String lsNow = now.format("%m-%d-%Y %I:%M:%S");
        lsNow += " just Started\n";
        try {
            dumpToFile("StepsChanged", lsNow);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
```

But if I put the statement right after

```
if(temporaryCountHolder == false)
```

statement, then the if statement with hasFinished will always evaluate to be false. How can I get it so that I can record the time if and only if the timer has finished?

Comment: Can you show how exactly you used `if(countDownTimer.hasFinished == true)` after `if(temporaryCountHolder == false)` ?

Comment: @JJPA I just added in how I used countDownTimer.hasFinished == true method in the post

Comment: does it come after `if(temporaryCountHolder == false){        countDownTimer.start();interrupted = true;}` or within this statement?

Comment: @JJPA yes it does. I noticed that if i put the if statement right after that, the countDownTimer will not be finished and as a result, hasFinished will be false and it'll never go into that if statement

Comment: Are you sure these statements are getting executed after the countdowntimer has finished?

Comment: They are not being executed after the countdowntimer has finished. I simply want that if the count down timer has finished, you record a time. how would i go about doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comments, the reason why you are getting the false value is because you are executing the statements before the timer has stopped.

You can go like below,

```
@Override
public void onFinish(){
        hasFinished = true;
        Time now = new Time(); //finds the current time
        now.setToNow(); 
        String lsNow = now.format("%m-%d-%Y %I:%M:%S");
        lsNow += " just Started\n";
        try {
            dumpToFile("StepsChanged", lsNow);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

To simply record the time you can just move those methods to the onFinish method of countdowntimer class. I don't know about `dumpToFile` if it is a method of another class you can make it a static method and use it or even some suitable alternative methods. Hope this helps.

Comment: wow Thanks! Just one question then. When CountDownTimer finishes, is onFinish automatically called without me invoking it?

Comment: Yes when the countdowntimer is finished the `onFinish` method is called automatically called as callback. `onFinish`-->`Callback fired when the time is up` as per doc.[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Answer (score 0):

you need to cancel CountDownTimer in OnFinsh

```
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        Log.v(TAG, "On Finish");
        Intent intent = new Intent(TIME_OUT);
        intent.putExtra("dialog", "timeout");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }
```