# How to finish CountdownTimer on back button

Tags: android, back, countdowntimer

I want to finish my CountdownTimer on Back button. I know that there a a few similar questions but that doesn´t help me with my problem.

I´ve got the following code in `onCreate()`

```
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {



            new CountDownTimer(10000, 550) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    for(int i = 0; i< arr.size(); i++){
                        Button aga = arr.get(i);
                        if(aga.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                            aga.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                    int zufall = (int) (Math.random()*23);
                    setNextButton(arr.get(zufall));
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {

                     System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

                    new CountDownTimer(10000, 350) {

                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            for(int i = 0; i< arr.size(); i++){
                                Button aga = arr.get(i);
                                if(aga.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                                    aga.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            }
                            int zufall = (int) (Math.random()*23);
                            setNextButton(arr.get(zufall));

                            System.out.println("HHH");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                           System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                            Intent highscore = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Highscore_eintragen.class);
                            highscore.putExtra("count", count);
                            startActivity(highscore);


                        }
                    }.start();
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }.start();
```

Now what I need is, if the user presses the back button during the `CountdownTimer` to finish my activity. Any solutions for that problem?

Comment: Did you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138348/how-to-stop-cancel-android-countdowntimer ?

Comment: Yes, I checked this link. But in this case I need to use CountdownTimer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call CountDownTimer.cancel():

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#cancel()

store reference to current CountDownTimer instance in your activity during creation, to have access to it inside Activity.

Comment: Can you give me a hint how to store a reference to CountDownTimer instance?

Comment: you simply hve new CountDownTimer() .. instead write it as mCountDownTimer = new C... and then access the instance mCountDownTimer as mentioned here.

Comment: Ok, great I got it.. And how can I check if CountDownTimer is started? Cause when I close one that is not started I get a Nullpointer..

Comment: @user896692 look in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941935/find-if-countdowntimer-is-finished